# Glide loading images each time when scrolling recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a `RecyclerView` and each item of `RecyclerView` is having `ImageView`.
I am loading the image in that `ImageView` using **Glide**, when I scroll down the `RecyclerView` it loads images and this is fine, but when I again srcoll up the `RecyclerView` it again loads those images which are already been loaded. I do not want to load that images again which have already been loaded.

**I am using the below code to load images using Glide**

```
Glide.with(mActivity)
                .load(img.getmGridViewImageUrl())
                .into(imageHolder.imageView);
```

Comment: post code of recycler view

Comment: HI, have you found the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 10):

You can cache the images either on disk or in Memory.

By default images are cached in Memory by Glide

### *It's also good to know that Glide will put all image resources into the memory cache by default. Thus, a specific call .skipMemoryCache( false ) is not necessary.*

If you want to enable cache in disk you can use one of the following

1. `DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE` caches only the original full-resolution
   image.
2. `DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT` caches only the final image, after reducing
   the resolution (and possibly transformations)
3. `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` caches all versions of the image (default
   behavior)

Usage :

```
Glide  
    .with( context )
    .load( url )
    .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
    .into( imageViewInternet );
```

Answer (score 0):

after doing this **diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT )**   also i am seeing in feedler that this is loading images from network.. i am just scrolling the grid recycler view..

Comment: Just use this `diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)`  that's the optimum you need to keep in cache.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly use this method do like below i will work

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
Glide.with( context )
            .load( imagesModelList.get(position).getUrl() ).apply(requestOptions)
            .into( holder.imageView );
    holder.delete_item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```